# remove duplicate from sorted array such that two duplicates are allowed

Tags: java

question: Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that duplicates appeared at most twice and return the new length.

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

My solution: This code is always missing on one index no matter what. Can someone please help me why ? For example my example input is supposed to return 6,but it returns 5.

```
int[] arr2= {1,1,1,2,3,4,4};
        int i=findDupsMedium(arr2);
        System.out.println(i);


static int findDupsMedium(int[] arr) {
    int index=0;
    if(arr.length>1) {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            arr[index++]=arr[i];

        }
    }

    //System.out.println("index:" + index);
    for(int ii=2;ii<arr.length;ii++ ) {
        int diff=ii-2;
        if(arr[ii] != arr[diff]) {

            arr[index++]=arr[ii];

        }
    }




    return index;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is ok, but missing some certain parts.

Here is a little bit dirty solution, it works for consecutive duplicates.

If input array has duplicates in different places, you have to implement another for loop.

```
static int findDupsMedium(int[] arr) {

    int count=0;

    //used for extracting duplicates from the length of array
    int extract=0;  

    if(arr.length>1) {

        // this is for having a comparison withot getting outOfBounds;
        int lastItem=0;      

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

            //If we had 2 duplicates and new one is the same with previous one, remove 
            if(count == 2 && lastItem == arr[i]){

                //if end of the array has duplicate, make it "-1"
                if(i==arr.length-1){
                    arr[i]=-1;
                }
                else{
                    extract++;  //we found a duplicate

                    lastItem = arr[i];

                    //shift it
                    for(int j=i;j<arr.length-1;j++){
                        arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                    }
                }
                //printArray(arr);                    

                count = 0;
            }
            else{

                if(arr[i+1]==arr[i]){
                    count++;
                    lastItem = arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return arr.length - extract;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work.  Try this `int[] arr2 = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5
      };`

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to keep track of the `length` of the array as it changes as well as when to update the main loop's `index`.

A `boolean` flag is also used to keep track of when a series of duplicates occur.

```java
   public static int findDupsMedium(int[] arr2) {
      int size = arr2.length;

      boolean foundFirstDuplicate = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length - 1; i++) {
         for (int k = i + 1; k < size;) {
            if (arr2[i] == arr2[k]) {
               if (foundFirstDuplicate) {
                  // If we're here, this must be third
                  // duplicate in a row so copy up the array
                  // overwriting the third dupe.
                  for (int g = k; g < arr2.length - 1; g++) {
                     arr2[g] = arr2[g + 1];
                  }
                  i--; // and readjust outer loop to stay in
                       // position
                  // and effective size of array is one smaller
                  // so adjust that
                  size--;
               }
               // set first time a duplicate is found and keep this set
               // until no more duplicates
               foundFirstDuplicate = true;
               break;
            }
            // no third or more duplicate so set to false
            foundFirstDuplicate = false;
            break;
         }
      }
      return size;
   }
```

To verify it works ok, add the folowing method

```
     static void display(int[] a, int size) {
         int[] t = Arrays.copyOf(a, size);
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
     }
```

And call the methods as follows:

```
      int[] arr2 = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5
      };
      int size = findDupsMedium(arr2);
      display(arr2, size);
```